# MathJax scripts not being generated by knitr::spin

Tags: r, knitr, mathjax, literate-programming

I'm generating an html report from a `knitr::spin` [marked up document](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/stitch/)

1) It works doing the following

```
> spin("document.R")
```

Process the resulting `.md` file in Rstudio by clicking the "Preview HTML" button, and then the "view the webpage with the system web browser" button.

2) However, the html file that is generated by `spin('document.R')` directly does not display LaTeX equations.

This is because (1) generates the MathJax scripts tags, but (2) does not.

Any ideas why not?

```
R 2.15.1> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] markdown_0.5.4 knitr_1.2     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.3   evaluate_0.4.3 formatR_0.7    stringr_0.6.2  tools_2.15.1
```

Answer (score 1):

`knitr::spin()` calls `markdown::markdownToHTML()`, which does include MathJax when math expressions are present. I cannot reproduce the problem with a minimal example:

```
#' A math expression $\alpha+\beta$. Below is a code chunk:
x <- 5
y <- 10
```

I can see the math expression after I save it as `test.R` and run `spin('test.R')`.